# submit on enter

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have something like this:

```
        <div style="float:left;"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#sign-in" data-toggle="modal"  data-dismiss="modal" ><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Sign-in</a></div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-small" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Close</a>
            <button class="btn-success btn-small" type="button" name="submit" value="login" onclick="forgotPassAjax();"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Send</button>
        </div>
```

in the  i need it to be clickable on enter, right now you have to manually use cursor to click the button, how do i make that happen? i saw some JS examples before, is there an easier way? right now it has a function onclick, that is generated in php for certain purpose, so what should i do?

Comment: `<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>` — Eugh. `i` means *italic* not icon!

Comment: Don't forget to use search before asking a question ;-)

Comment: @Quentin let's refer to the spec: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-i-element

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle — There isn't a span of text there, so its wrong if you use the recommendation or the "living standard".

Comment: @Quentin I think I agree with you. Semantically the i element shouldn't be used that way, but devs do. I just wanted to point people to the specification so they can have authoritative fact. That being said, you were wrong to think that it means italic.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle — "I: Renders as italic text style." — [the most recent non-draft HTML recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-I)

Comment: @Quentin This is a candidate recommendation, not a draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle – Still not a recommendation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21333/discussion-between-patrick-james-mcdougle-and-quentin)

Comment: Let's not. It isn't a useful conversation.

Comment: i agree, about the i, it actually confused me at first, but yeah bootstrap is not very practical. It wasn't my choice. It was a project that we assigned to India, oh well

Comment: and yeah i saw some of those answers on overflow before, i just wasnt sure if there was any other way of doing it, but those below seem to work

Answer (score 3):

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("keydown", processKeyEvents);
$(document).on("keypress", processKeyEvents);

function processKeyEvents(event) {
     if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        forgotPassAjax();
     }
}
```

You can replace $(document) with $("id of focused element") to restrict the range of the keypress.

Comment: Note, that this will work through hole document, not only when you are editing input.

Answer (score 0):

Surround this with form tags and then use, change the button type to submit.

```
$("form-selector").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
 //perform other stuff here
});
```

Not tested it though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery syntax

```
$(document).on("keydown", enterPress);
$(document).on("keypress", enterPress);

function enterPress(e) {
     if ( e.which == 13 ) { //if the key press is enter (13)
        $('button').click();
     }
}
```

Replace document with the id of your modal or input (ex : '#modal') and 'button' with your button id (ex 'myButton')

Answer (score 0):

another jquery example could be this:

```
$(document).on("keydown keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        forgotPassAjax();
    }
});
```